# Unable to store the response data of http in angular js to a local variable in controller and manipulate that variable?

Tags: angularjs

A Facory for http request from a json file.

```
           myApp.factory('contactFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

            var promise = $http.get('directiveJSON.json');                        
            return promise;

             }]);
```

Writing the then function of promise in controller, now I need to store the value of promise2.data into local variable x and do something on x. Is it possible?Right now console.log(x) wont be containing the response data.

```
 myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','contactFactory',function(scope,p) {

     var x;
     p.then(function(promise2) {
     console.log(promise2.data);
     scope.data=promise2.data;
     x=promise2.data;
    });

console.log(x);
   }]);
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  This code doesn't even show you trying to do what you asked.

Comment: The data won't be available in console.log(x)....how to access the response data out of the scope of that function

Comment: the statement `p.then` is putting that function block in a callback, and then immediately trying to use `console.log(x)` to consume the data before the callback that would set `x` has returned.

Comment: How to use the response value outside the function p.then() in the controller..preferrably store it variable x so that i can use x outside where i want?

Comment: you put all your statements in the callback, or you return a new promise.

Comment: No other way than recursively returning promises or putting every other manipulation statement inside callback?

Comment: you could use an event listener to watch for when the value of x changes, and then perform your logic.

Comment: Yeah that was helpful :) ..

Comment: anything that is inside the `.then` is going to happen in the future, any thing outside the `.then` is going to happen now.  You can't use a variable now that won't have a value until the future, that's just how JavaScript callbacks work.